# Spark/Databricks: `collect()`ing Large Datasets in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks

Background: I'm working on a pilot project to assess the pros and cons of using DataBricks to train models using R. I am using a dataset that occupies about 5.7GB of memory when loaded into a pandas dataframe. The data are stored in a delta table in Unity Catalog.

Problem: I can `collect()` the data using python (pyspark) in about 2 minutes. However, when I tried to use sparklyr to collect the same dataset in R the command was still running after ~2.5 days. I can't load the dataset into DBFS first because we need stricter data-access controls than DBFS will allow. Below are screenshots of the cells that I ran to `collect()` the data in Python and R.

I'm hoping that I'm just missing something about how sparklyr loads data.

Here is the cell that loads the data using pyspark, you can see that it took 2.04 minutes to complete:
[image: collecting data using python]

Here is the cell that loads the data using sparklyr, you can see that I cancelled it after 2.84 days. For context, I'm using the `sdf_collect()` function because if I'm reading [the sparklyr source](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/blob/main/R/sdf_wrapper.R#L175) correctly then this function will use the same Apache Arrow optimizations that `toPandas()` uses in pyspark.
[image]

I also tried using the `sparklyr::spark_read_table` function but I got an error that `Table or view not found: main.databricks_...` which I think must be because the table is in a metastore managed by Unity Catalog.

Environment Info:

- Databricks Runtime: 10.4 LTS
- Driver Node Size: 140GB memory and 20 cores
- Worker Nodes: 1 worker node with 56GB of memory and 8 cores.
- R libraries installed: arrow, sparklyr, SparkR, dplyr

Comment: Can you try SparkR instead? I have seen problems with Arrow serialization when yougin sparklyr... Also, I don't think that Unity Catalog is supported as of right now.

Comment: @AlexOtt, when I use `SparkR::collect` I get a JVM error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me, using `sparklyr` syntax:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery("USE CATALOG main") 

sc %>% 
  tbl("main.metabricks_benchmarking.analytic_file_20221007") %>% 
  collect
```

So it seems `sparklyr` can work with the Unity Catalog, you just need to add a `USE CATALOG` query first. Does this run faster than the `invoke` queries for you?